# Run a Hadoop job without output file

Tags: hadoop

Is it possible to run a hadoop job without specifying output file ?
When i try to run a hadoop job , no output file specified Exception is thrown .
can any one please give any procedure to do so using Java.

I am writing the data processed by reduce to a non relational database so i no longer require it to write to HDFS.

Comment: You need to supply more information about what you've tried and what you're trying to do.  What is the purpose of running your MR job?  For it to be meaningful it will be producing output of some kind.  Where does it go?  Not HDFS, obviously.  Does it go to HBase or some external store or service?

Comment: Sorry for it , I have update my Question .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't really do this. Writing output is part of the framework. When you work outside of the framework, you basically have to just deal with the consequences.

You can use [NullOutputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/NullOutputFormat.html), which doesn't write any data to HDFS. I think it still creates the folder, though. You could always let Hadoop create the folder, then [delete it](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#delete%28org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20boolean%29).

Comment: FYI NullOutputFormat doesn't require an output folder to be defined, so should give you what you need